# How to serialize random data?

Tags: go

I have double-linked list:

```
type node[T any] struct {
    info T
    next *node[T]
    prev *node[T]
}

type List[T any] struct {
    head *node[T]
    tail *node[T]
    size int
}
```

And I want method `func (list List[T]) ToByte() (error, []byte)` which will return bytes of any data in this list. I have tried some approaches, for example, using `binary.Write()`, but it won't work with any data (for example, it won't work with strings).

It seems to me that it is possible to do this, because any data is stored in memory as bytes, all I need to do is simply pull out all the bytes from memory.

Comment: you could use `encoding/gob` but regardless which encoding you choose, your constraint is `any` so it admits *literally anything*, including types whose serialization would be nonsense, like chans and functions. You should restrict the constraint first

Comment: As far as I know, encoding/gob assumes usage of Encoder and Decoder type, that is, I must store and transmit it. I do not want it. I assume that using the method ToByte() the user knows what he is doing and translates his data into bytes, knowing how to decode them back. More generally, I need this method to make hash of the list of some values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `encoding/gob` which works better with Go types and is more efficient than say `encoding/json` or `encoding/xml`, but still it can't encode functions and channels types and recursive values (but recursive types works fine), so you can't really use `any` as constraint

Here's an example of `ToByte` using `encoding/gob`: https://go.dev/play/p/A5hCXCCThm6